# visibility back to 'visible' : video auto-play only if was not on pause before

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I can pause a video when visibity is changed to hidden, and play the video when visibility is back to visible. Like that :

```
    var userManuallyPause = false;

    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var documentTitle = document.title;

    var updateTitleForVideo = function(state){
        if (state === '') {
            document.title = documentTitle;
            return;
        };

        document.title = documentTitle + ' [' + state + ']';
    };

    video.onpause = function(){
        userManuallyPause = true;
        updateTitleForVideo('Paused');
    };

    video.onplay = function(){
        updateTitleForVideo('');
    };

    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
        var state = document.visibilityState;

        if (!video.paused) {
            if (state === 'hidden') {
                video.pause();
                userManuallyPause = false;
                updateTitleForVideo('Paused');
            }
        }
        else if (state === 'visible' && !userManuallyPause) { video.play(); }
    });
```

But if the video is already on pause before visibility goes to hidden, I don't want the video to play when I go back to visible.

Is that possible ? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a variable such as `var userManuallyPause = false`, and if the user pauses it him/herself, you can set that variable to true. When the user unpauses, you can set it back to false.

Then in your code above, you add a check of

```
if (!userManuallyPause) { ... }
```

and it should run as expected.

Comment: But how ?    How can I differentiate a user manually pause and the event generated pause ?

Comment: I'm guessing the user manual pause is generated by an onClick event on a pause button. On that event you set the variable.

Comment: I cannot make it. Unless I see a full working example, I think this is not possible.

Comment: How are you letting the user pause?

Comment: Can the user pause manually with this code? I see no event calling video.onpause() from user click or anything.